# Why does operators bl_idname have to contain 1 dot?

Tags: python, add-on

Since anything before and after the dot is arbitrary, why bother?

Related error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Registering operator class: 'abcdefg', invalid bl_idname 'abcdefg', must contain 1 '.' character
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This rule may seem arbitrary, but looks like there's already some structure in existing operator's names. All registered operators will end up within [`bpy.ops`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.ops.html) module, and we can see that identifiers directly under it is reserved for modules/namespaces further categorizing the operators:

- [`bpy.ops.action`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.ops.action.html) for animation data,
- [`bpy.ops.object`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.ops.object.html) for object, regardless of data type,
- [`bpy.ops.ui`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.ops.ui.html) for user interface,
- etc.

When we need an operator to quit Blender, it's available, grouped with other [window management](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender) operators.

At first I, too, didn't bother with naming, putting everything under `bpy.ops.object`. But namespace distinction really helps to document, browse and search all the operators. Predictable identifier + Python console's *Autocomplete* feature made it easier to discover and build upon existing operators, including those from other addons.

I don't know if it has any other significance, but *self-documentation* alone made the naming rule worthwhile to enforce.

Answer (score 10):

Developer note: in C code blenders operators are formatted `SOME_OT_operator`, which gets converted to `some.operator` in Python. To ensure the conversion can be done the "." needs to be added.

Then we can expose all operators as `bpy.ops.some.operator()` too, which is neat/logical.

This is arbitrary and we could have chosen not to do it, but I think having each tool in a named category is a good thing.