# Why are these buttons performing the same operation?

Tags: python, add-on, operator

I'm writing a simple script that will help me use Blender better.
One script sets everything up that's needed for retopology. The second just makes a hexagon and fan fills its face.

Individually, I can get these scripts to function correctly, but when I add them both together, or when I add them as separate scripts, the one that executes first will be the operation that both buttons will be caused to execute.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Dope Tools",
    "author": "Digital Dope",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds several features to blender that I need",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
    }

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector

class AddRetopoSU(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, axis=(1, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SHRINKWRAP')
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_clip = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].show_on_cage = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subsurf"].show_on_cage = True
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.100995, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True, use_accurate=False)
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_snap = True
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_element = 'VERTEX'
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_snap_align_rotation = True
        bpy.context.object.show_all_edges = True
        return {'FINISHED'}

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        AddRetopoSU.bl_idname,
        text="Add Retopo",
        icon='MOD_SHRINKWRAP')

class AddHex(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Hexagon"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=5, radius=1, fill_type='TRIFAN', view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
        return {'FINISHED'}

def add_Hex_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        AddHex.bl_idname,
        text="Add Hexagon",
        icon='MESH_ICOSPHERE')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddHex)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.prepend(add_Hex_button)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddRetopoSU)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.prepend(add_object_button)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddHex)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_Hex_button)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddRetopoSU)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Give it a unique `bl_idname`**

Both operators have the same `bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"`. When you register you are effectively overriding the first with the second.

Give it a name like

```
bl_idname = "mesh.add_retopo"
```

and call it in code with

```
bpy.ops.mesh.add_retopo()
```

or use its, now unique id in the UI layout.

```
layout.operator("mesh.add_retopo")
```

Links.

[Why does operators bl_idname have to contain 1 dot?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/why-does-operators-bl-idname-have-to-contain-1-dot)

Comment: THat worked! Thank you! But now I have to find a way to make the name and icon unique. as it stands they now have the same label and icon because the "text" and "icon" variables cannot be changed. Could I use text.hex= and text.retopo= (a dot to make them unique?)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Blender uses `xxxx.yyyy` to name its operators. xxxx is object for object operators _by convention_, but can use any lower case name dot name.  When the operator is registered it becomes `bpy.ops.xxxx.yyyy()` and can be added to layout by its id `"xxxx.yyyy"`.   If another is registered with same id it overwrites the previously defined (prob in q) On the menu,  There is no need for the text argument as it already uses `bl_label` by default. Could add `icon = 'SOME_ICON'` as a class variable, and use `layout.operator(AddHex.bl_idname, icon = AddHex.icon` )` ?

Comment: You have answered my question. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm a few days old to this.... Thank you so much for you time and consideration! I appreciate it.